# How to control the number of iterations in a loop with a button?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, button

I would like to control the iterations of a loop with a click button.

For example, the following code, with just one click, prints this:

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
```

---

**HTML**

```
<h1>Controlling loop iterations with "Click"</h1>    
<button type="submit" style="width: 80px" name="submit" onclick="main()">Submit</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function main() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = loopFunction();
}

function loopFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i++;
    }

    return text;
}
```

I would like to click the "submit" button and run the loop one iteration (step) at a time:

For example:

```
click "submit" = The number is 0
click "submit" = The number is 1
click "submit" = The number is 2
click "submit" = The number is 3
click "submit" = The number is 4
```

Comment: Why don't you put the content of your loop in a function and call it on every click event of the submit? You can store variables like `i` in a global context to access and modify it at each call.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of iteration here :) The button click just increases the i variable, and prints the The number is {i} ? or I didn't understand what you want to do

Comment: @michip96 storing variables in global context is a bad idea . It can be stored in function as cached property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generator function for this purpose.

```
    function* loopFunction() {
        var i = 0;

        while (i < 5) {
            yield "<br>The number is " + i;
            i++;
        }
    }
    var iterator=loopFunction(); // init generator; no return
    function main(){
        var res=iterator.next(); // returns {value:<result>,done:false|true}
        if(!res.done)
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+=res.value;
        else
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+='<br />No more results';
        return false;
    }

    <button type="submit" style="width: 80px" name="submit" onclick="return main()">Submit</button> 
<!--"return" is important to avoid submission -->
    <p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: Hi Alex Kudryashev! Your answer was exactly what I was looking for! I learned so much with your code!!! Thanks so much again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this.

```
function loopFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i = loopFunction.cachedValue ? loopFunction.cachedValue : 0;
    var max = 5;

    if(loopFunction.cachedValue >= max){
       return false;
    }

    text += "<br>The number is " + i;

    if(!loopFunction.cachedValue){
        loopFunction.cachedValue = 0;
    }

    loopFunction.cachedValue++;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Concatenation `i` variable to `text ` variable makes no sens here . If you are going to update some dom element content, then change text variable to be linked to that dom object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a loop. Put the `i` **outside** the function and **increment** it **in** the function. Set `i` to 0, **if** it is bigger than 5.

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var i = 0;
function main() {
    text.innerHTML += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    if(i > 5) {
        i = 0;
        text.innerHTML = "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
    i += 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5o9s78d/)

Comment: Hi Peter Leger! Thanks so much for your help! That´s what I was looking for! Your idea works excellent!! Again, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If all you wish to accomplish is to do one iteration at a time, why iterate at all?

You could simply use a global `variable` to retain your count value.

```js
var count = 0;
        
function main() {
    var textElement = document.getElementById("text");

    if (count >= 5) {
        count = 0;
        textElement.innerHTML = "";
    }

    textElement.innerHTML += "<br>" + "The number is " + count++;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" style="width: 80px" name="submit" onclick="main();">Submit</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Which would give you `The number is X` for each click; as shown in the above snippet.

Unless I misunderstood your conundrum, this seems to be the solution you are looking for.